# What happens when we create a common user specifying CONTAINER=CURRENT in Oracle Database?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

What happens when we create a **common user** specifying **CONTAINER=CURRENT**?
Considering the following create user statement :

```
CREATE USER c##comm_user IDENTIFIED BY comm_pwd CONTAINER = CURRENT;
```

Will that user still be a common user? If so, what is the difference between specifying CURRENT or ALL for the container, for both application containers or CDB container?